# Equivalence partitioning, it this an incorrect example in a book?

Tags: testing, equivalence-classes

I am trying to understand this topic and starting with the very basic one (not discrete domain), I believe this is not correct.

I cannot post images yet so the description goes like this:

```
Income is greater than 0 and lesser than 500 = tax 0  
Income is greater than 500 and lesser than 1300 = tax 30  
Income is greater than 1300 and lesser than 5000 = tax 40
```

They define invalid class for negative numbers, valid for 0-500 and 500 to 1300, and INVALID for 1300 to 5000.
I think it is a mistake and the invalid class is bounded by 5000 and goes to infinity.
Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there is a mistake, as you mentioned.
There are 3 valid input classes and two invalid which are out of the range, i.e. below 0 or above 5 000.